# Swagger 2 or 3 for Spring Data Rest

Tags: swagger, spring-data-rest, openapi, springfox, springdoc

I have a spring boot application using spring data rest. I have a problem in providing a well read API documentation using swagger. I tried spring fox and springdoc, but each has its problems

1. Spring fox:

- I can not change the tag name of a repository, only the description
- No support for projections
- No support of openAPI3 yet (this is actually not a big problem)

2. Springdoc (https://springdoc.org/)

- I can not change neither the tag name nor the description (@Tag does not work on repos)
- No support for projections
- The same repo gets 3 tags e.g. books-entity-controller, books-search-controller (with methods of a parent class) and books-property-reference-controller (with unnecessary listing of /{id}/{property} urls)

Any better way? I like spring fox for not providing more than one tag, also the auto generated tag names are better e.g. Books Entity instead of books-entity-controller. But it would be better either to customize it or find a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand [Spring REST Docs](https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs) over Swagger. Spring REST Docs is test-driven to guarantee your API documentation is always sync with your API.
[Andy's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5ncCJBarRI) explains more why Spring REST Docs is more suitable than Swagger for API documentation.

You can find [offical simple guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-restdocs/) and more [samples](https://spring.io/projects/spring-restdocs#samples).

My [Github project](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline) uses it. You can clone the repository and have a look at the generated documentation HTML [/sga-booking/index.html](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline/blob/develop/sga-booking/index.html).
Related Spring REST Docs file are

- [FltApiDocumentation.java](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline/blob/develop/sga-flt-sch/src/test/java/com/yejianfengblue/sga/fltsch/flt/FltApiDocumentation.java)
- [flts.adoc](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline/blob/develop/sga-flt-sch/src/main/asciidoc/flts.adoc)
- [BookingApiDocumentation.java](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline/blob/develop/sga-booking/src/test/java/com/yejianfengblue/sga/booking/booking/BookingApiDocumentation.java)
- [booking.adoc](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline/blob/develop/sga-booking/src/main/asciidoc/booking.adoc)

If you find my Github useful, consider give it a star.

Answer (score 1):

**Springdoc**

> I can not change neither the tag name nor the description (@Tag does not work on repos)

and

> The same repo gets 3 tags

You can customize it. Use the following at the controller-class level.

```java
@Tag(name = "Name of the Tag", description = "Description of the tag")
```

or

```java
@Tags(value = {
    // Multiple @Tag annotations separated by comma ,
})
```

or the following at the method level.

```java
@Operation(tags = {"Tag 1", "Tag 2"})
```

**Remember:**

- `@Tag` at a class level will override the operation level tags for the particular class.
- A class level tag can have only 1 value.

So if you need a controller to have multiple tags, you should isolate it in a different class that doesn't have the `@Tag` at the class level.

> No support for projections

I have never used projections. I generally use the `@JsonIgnore` to eliminate the ones not needed, but depends on your use-case.

If you want to hide something from a schema, use can use the below method

```java
@Schema(description = "Example POJO to demonstrate the hidden attribute")
class Example {
    ...
    @Schema(hidden = true)    // <--- Will be hidden from the Swagger UI completely 
    String exampleId;
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps. Drop a comment for any clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I use Spring Data REST. Your solution applies on a normal Spring MVC application

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had not worked with Spring Data REST yet, so was not aware of it. :)

Comment: `@Tags` works and solved problem with `-search-controller`.   
See also https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/834